# (BackboneJS) Executar uma View após retorno do servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, backbone

Na minha aplicação eu tenho 2 *Views*.

Uma delas está enviando os dados para o servidor quando o cliente clica no *submit*.

A outra precisa esperar essa resposta e executar para trabalhar com os dados 'atualizados'.

Como eu faria tal coisa?

Comment: Quando a primera view é submetida você faz uma requisição ajax? Não da para fazer a ação da segunda view no callback dessa requisição?

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais fácil seria utilizar os recursos nativos da collection do backbone.

1. Substituir o input type submit por um input type button (ou uma div) para não ter que ficar cancelando o comportamento default do elemento HTML.

**Opção 1:**

2. Realizar a inserção (POST) via collection.

   - Na *view 1* criar um model com os valores que seriam submetidos pelo form.
   - Adicionar o model criado à collection com 'create' para assim adicionar e realizar o request para o server enviando o novo model ([backbone-collection-create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)).
3. Na *view 2* utilizar uma nova collection apontando para a mesma url, e escutar o evento de add para adicionar o novo item inserido na collection (server) utilizando o 'fetch' com a opção de remove como false caso não queira que toda a collection seja atuzalizada: ([backbone-collection-fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch))

   `collection.fetch({remove: false});`

**Opção 2:**

2. Na *view 1* realizar a inserção (POST) via JSON (ou JSONP no caso de cross domain);
3. Na *view 2*:

   - Escutar o evento de add da mesma forma do exemplo acima.
   - Ou realizar um trigger ([backbone-trigger](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger)) da *view 1* para a *view 2* passando o novo model e adicionar manualmente na view (escutar na *view 1* o evento disparado pelo trigger e realizar um 'append' do HTML com os dados dos novo model que foram passados via trigger).